# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'AudioContext': The number of hardware contexts provided (6)

Tags: google-chrome, speech-to-text, audiocontext, domexception, bing-speech

i am trying to implement microsoft bing speech api and its working fine for the first 5 times after that when i record my voice i getting exception in console .
Exception : Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'AudioContext': The number of hardware contexts provided (6) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (6).

when i try to close with  AudioContext.close() it shows another error like "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Cannot close a context that is being closed or has already been closed."
 Anybody know whats the error is this . i am using speech 1.0.0 js sdk of microsoft bing speech .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution to resolve this problem, i just closed the audio context when the recording stops and its working fine for me :)

here is the edited speech.js stop method :`

```
Speech.prototype.stop = function () {
        if (this._currentSource) {
            // context will be closed here
            this.context.close(); // new added code for the continues context creation (To avoid DoM exception)


    };`
```