# How to go back and forth between two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where I am currently trying to generate tone using audio context. Here is what I came up so far:

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
    var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var osc = context.createOscillator(); // instantiate an oscillator
    osc.type = 'sine'; // this is the default - also square, sawtooth, triangle
    osc.frequency.value = 440; // Hz
    osc.connect(context.destination); // connect it to the destination
    osc.start(); // start the oscillator
    osc.stop(context.currentTime + 1);
    })
```

I got the solution from stackoverflow. It perfectly makes the tone I am looking for. However, it only works for only less than six activation. In other words, when I click the button(with id === "btn") more than six times, it no longer makes the tone.

Here is jsFiddle.net link that has the same syntax as above [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/3tubdufn/)

Can you help me fix the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511096/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-construct-audiocontext-the-number-of-hardwar and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046470/failed-to-construct-audiocontext-number-of-hardware-contexts-reached-maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `context.close()` after the `osc.stop`. But this is not so trivial because if you call it right after, it will not even play the audio because it's async.

A solution would be to put it inside a `setTimeout`:

```
// ...
osc.start();
osc.stop(context.currentTime + 1);
setTimeout(function () {
  osc.close();
}, 1000); // 1000 = 1s used at .stop
```

Alterantively, you could do both `.stop`. and `.close` inside `setTimeout`:

```
// ...
osc.start();
setTimeout(function () {
  osc.stop(); // note that there is no when argument, i.e. stop immetidately  
  osc.close();
}, 1000);
```

In my opinion, the second option is better since you don't have to match stop and timeout times.

---

The code example from the question, updated with the answer:

```js
$("#one").click(function(){
  var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  var osc = context.createOscillator(); // instantiate an oscillator
  osc.type = 'sine'; // this is the default - also square, sawtooth, triangle
  osc.frequency.value = 440; // Hz
  osc.connect(context.destination); // connect it to the destination
  osc.start(); // start the oscillator
  setTimeout(function () {
    osc.stop();
    context.close();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search">
<button id="one">
hello
</button>
```